# msaccess workgroup information file

Tags: ms-access

I have a VB applicaiton with MS-Access database. The access database is protected with workgroup administration file.

I understood that, to add a workgroup file we need to goto `Tools-> Security -> Workgroup Administrator` to add the work group file. In MS-Access 2007, we have to put some commands in the VBA IDE (or we need to create macro)

My question is: If many users required the same database, do we need to add the workgroup information file in each users machine?

Thanks in advance,
Ramesh.PB

Answer (score 1):

Normally all users use the same workgroup file on a shared folder. You set that in the application shortcut:

```
C:\...\MSACCESS.EXE c:\data\Northwind_be.mdb /wrkgrp c:\developer.mdw
```

See [this page](http://www.vb123.com/toolshed/05_access/workgroupfiles_shortcuts.htm)

If you don't do it that way, your security changes won't be reflected to users until the workgroup db is copied to their pc !